# Kubernetes services networking

Tags: networking, kubernetes

Ive been been trying to get spark working on kubernetes on my local machine.
However I`m having an issue trying to understand how the networking of services work.

I`m running kubernetes in containers on my laptop:

- Etcd 2.0.5.1
- Kubelet 1.1.2
- Proxy 1.1.2
- SkyDns 2015-03-11-001
- Sky2kube 1.11

Then i`m launching spark which is located in the examples of the kubernetes github repo.

kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/spark-master-controller.yaml
kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/spark-master-service.yaml
kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/spark-webui.yaml
kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/spark-worker-controller.yaml
kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/zeppelin-controller.yaml
kubectl create -f kubernetes/examples/spark/zeppelin-service.yaml

My local network: 10.7.64.0/24
My docker network: 172.17.0.1/16

What works:

- Spark master launches and I can connect to the webUI.
- Spark worker tries to do dns query for spark-master and is
  successful. (it returns the correct service ip of the master)

What does not work:

- Spark worker cannot connect to the service ip. there is no route to
  this host in that container nor on the local machine(laptop).   Also
  I see nothing happening in iptables. It tries to connect to somewhere
  in the 10.0.0.0/8 network which i don`t have any routing too. Can
  someone shed a light on this ?

Details:

How I start the containers:

sudo docker run \
        --net=host \
            -d kubernetes/etcd:2.0.5.1 \
            /usr/local/bin/etcd \
                    --addr=$(hostname -i):4001 \
                        --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 \
                            --data-dir=/var/etcd/data

sudo docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.2.0 \
    /hyperkube kubelet --containerized --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" --address="0.0.0.0" --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --cluster-dns=10.7.64.184 --cluster-domain=kubernetes.local

sudo docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google-containers/hyperkube:v1.2.0  /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2 --cluster-dns=10.7.64.184 --cluster-domain=kubernetes.local --cloud-provider=""

sudo docker run -d --net=host --restart=always          \
                gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11           \
                -v=10 -logtostderr=true -domain=kubernetes.local \
                -etcd-server="http://127.0.0.1:4001"

sudo docker run -d --net=host --restart=always         \
                -e ETCD_MACHINES="http://127.0.0.1:4001"        \
                -e SKYDNS_DOMAIN="kubernetes.local"             \
                -e SKYDNS_ADDR="10.7.64.184:53"                     \
                -e SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS="8.8.8.8:53,8.8.4.4:53"   \
                gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-03-11-001

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the issue was, the proxy was not running due to --cluster-dns and --cluster-domain not being parameters of the proxy. Now the iptables are created and the spark workers are able to connect to the service ip of the spark-master.